# Need help with simple digital circuit that can change state and reset

Tags: digital-logic

It's been 20 years since I have used any digital logic circuits, so please explain things well and be patient. I just need a simple digital circuit that does the following: When the input state changes (Low to high or high to low) the output goes to high. Then there needs to be a momentary switch to reset the output back to low. It's as simple as that. I have searched Google, but I think I that I just don't know the correct terms to be using or maybe the answer is staring me in the face and I just don't know it. Any suggestions are examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it back to original state which turned the input or back to low? Please re-look the question.

Comment: do detect "input state changes", you will need a delay of some kind.

Comment: I'm not 100% following your question. I'll try to clarify. The reset switch needs to always set the output to low, regardless of whether the current output state is high or low. The input will always start low and the output will be low. Once the input goes high, the output goes high. Then the reset can toggle the output back to low. Then when the input goes low, the output is toggled back to high. Then the reset switch can reset the output back to low. This just repeats. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy758c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What value for the resistor and capacitor? I tried different values, but it's not working right.

Comment: If it is humans pressing the switch, try 100k & 0.1 uF.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This circuit should work for you. Just please try to observe notations with patience. My bad drawings.